# XML Deserialization Issue with different XMLRoot Name

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, deserialization, xml-deserialization

**De-Serializing Class**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "sgr")]
public class SongGroup
{
    public SongGroup()
    {
        this.Songs = new List<Song>();
    }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sgs")]
    public List<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}

public class Song
{
    [XmlElement("a")]
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("s")]
    public string SongTitle { get; set; }
}
```

**C# Code**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SongGroup songs = new SongGroup();
        for(int i =0; i<5;i++)
        {
            Song song = new Song();
            song.Artist = "Artist " + i;
            song.SongTitle = "Title " + i;

            songs.Songs.Add(song);
        }
        SaveSongs(songs);
    }

    public static bool SaveSongs(SongGroup songs)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SongGroup));
        using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("mysongxml.xml"))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, songs);
        }
        //var xDocument = XDocument.Load("mysongxml2.xml"); // need to it working

        var xDocument = XDocument.Load("mysongxml.xml"); //works fine

        string xmlString = xDocument.ToString();

        var serializer2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SongGroup));
        var reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
        var instance = (SongGroup)serializer2.Deserialize(reader);
        return true;
    }
```

**mysongxml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sgr xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <sgs>
    <a>Artist 0</a>
    <s>Title 0</s>
  </sgs>
  <sgs>
    <a>Artist 1</a>
    <s>Title 1</s>
  </sgs>
  <sgs>
    <a>Artist 2</a>
    <s>Title 2</s>
  </sgs>
  <sgs>
    <a>Artist 3</a>
    <s>Title 3</s>
  </sgs>
  <sgs>
    <a>Artist 4</a>
    <s>Title 4</s>
  </sgs>
</sgr>
```

**mysongxml2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfSong xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Song>
    <Artist>Artist 0</Artist>
    <SongTitle>Title 0</SongTitle>
  </Song>
  <Song>
    <Artist>Artist 1</Artist>
    <SongTitle>Title 1</SongTitle>
  </Song>
  <Song>
    <Artist>Artist 2</Artist>
    <SongTitle>Title 2</SongTitle>
  </Song>
  <Song>
    <Artist>Artist 3</Artist>
    <SongTitle>Title 3</SongTitle>
  </Song>
  <Song>
    <Artist>Artist 4</Artist>
    <SongTitle>Title 4</SongTitle>
  </Song>
</ArrayOfSong>
```

My problem is that when the root name is `sgr` everything works fine but I need the same to get working with `ArrayOfSong` as well.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what you need is my answer from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303140/deserializing-xml-into-class-c-sharp). Remove the `root` from `Song` and correctly configure the `Songs` property.

Comment: @AndreiV thanks, for the reply I have updated the same in my question, and tried the same but my problem is i have to load 2 different xml with different root name one is `sgr` and other is `ArrayOfSongs`

Comment: Hmm... Ok, I get it now. Why are there two different tag name sets? The structure is the same. If you have control over the serialization of (a least) on XML, make it so that it matches the second one.

Comment: @AndreiV No I have no control on Serialization, Its Just the different versions where RootName and Namespaces have changed :(

Comment: I think that you have two options here: either create another set of classes, with different serialization attributes, or create your own serializer.

Comment: @AndreiV do you have any link or examples for the same?

Comment: No, I don't. But there are a lot of examples out there. You can easily find them using Google.

Comment: @AndreiV What I've done is I created a new XmlDocument and created a default RootName then appending the InnerXml of the old xml to new xml is this correct way to do it?
It's working but the data is not getting to me :(

Comment: I don't think it would work, because of the root name, which doesn't match on the "base" class. I think your best option is to create a [custom XML serializer](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=c%23%20custom%20xml%20deserialization&safe=off).